# Create an Firestore Client crash in Xamarin Forms [ Could not resolve type with token 0100003b]

Tags: c#, firebase, xamarin, google-cloud-firestore

I got a problem for few days, i'm trying to access to firestore in xamarin forms. To do so I am using the environment variable `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` as you can see in the code below. The environment variable stting is successfull as you can see I did some test and everything is ok about this part. But when I call the method `FirestoreClient.Create()` I got this exception:

> System.TypeLoadException: Could not resolve type with token 0100003b (from typeref, class/assembly System.Runtime.Loader.AssemblyLoadContext, System.Runtime.Loader, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)

I'm using Google.Cloud.Firestore and Google.Cloud.Firestore.V1Beta1 both on version 1.0.0-beta02

Here is the code :

```
    public void InitializeFirestore()
    {
        var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        Stream steam = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("AIGallery.AppMobile.CarouselReservation.FirestoreDir.Book-A-Room-Bot-13b38d0674e5.json");
        string text = "";


        //I create the json files to get the path, because can't get the path from an embedded ressource
        string json = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "creditential.json");
        //Here I just copy past the json file from google inside creditential.json
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(steam))
        {
            text = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
        using (var w = new StreamWriter(json))
        {
            w.WriteLine(text);
            w.Flush();
        }
        //Here was just to be sure everything was wirtten inside json, it works 
        text = "";
        using (var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(json))
        {
            text = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
        //Set the variable
        System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS", json);
        //See the content, worked well 
        var t = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS");
        //Here on Create, it crash
        client = FirestoreClient.Create();
```

I'm trying to find out what is wrong for few days, can't figure it out. Thanks in advance

Comment: I think it's the same issue as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46765179/xamarin-grpc-could-not-resolve-type-with-token-0100002b

Comment: You're right, thank you ! So no solution for the moment !